# Unable to add custom data with AZ CLI az create vm command

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am running the below command to create a VM on my resource group, however when I login, I don't see the file `/root/hello.txt`.

```
az vm create --name "my_vm" --resource-group "my_rg" --image "centos" --admin-username "centos" --os-disk-size-gb "100" --vnet-name "my_vnet" --subnet "public-4" --ssh-key-values "ssh-rsa ..." --size "Standard_DS1_v2" --nsg "my_nsg" --custom-data '#!/bin/bash
        touch /root/hello.txt
        ' --data-disk-sizes-gb "10"
```

Granted, there are newlines that didn't paste nicely, but it shouldn't matter.
Also, I don't want to pass a file path. I need to pass the text, just like I do for AWS.

The ultimate goal is to run below bash script to increase the partition of the OS disk, which is far too small.

```
#!/bin/sh
fdisk /dev/sda <<EOF
u
p
d
2
n
p
2


w
EOF
touch fdisk.log
reboot
xfs_growfs -d /dev/sda2
touch xfs.log
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the Custom Data is a script or other metadata that can be injected into a Microsoft Azure virtual machine **at provision time**. Currently, there are [cloud-init preinstalled and configured images](http://cloud-init%20support%20for%20virtual%20machines%20in%20Azure) in Azure. It can act on the custom data sent during provisioning using a cloud-init configuration file or simply a shell script (as long as it starts with `#!`, then cloud-init will execute it).

> On Linux, this data is passed to the VM via the `ovf-env.xml` file,
>   which is copied to the `/var/lib/waagent` directory during provisioning.
>   Newer versions of the Microsoft Azure Linux Agent will also copy the
>   base64-encoded data to `/var/lib/waagent/CustomData` as well for
>   convenience.

Read [Custom Data and Cloud-Init on Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-data-and-cloud-init-on-windows-azure/) for more details.

Generally, Custom data is sent to the VM along with the **other provisioning configuration information** such as the new hostname, username, password, certificates and keys, etc. In this case, I don't think you can resize the partition of the OS disk using custom data at the provision time. It seems that it's impossible to do a reboot and interactive processing scripts in the custom data.

For more references, you can read

[Resizing a Linux VM system disk in Microsoft Azure](https://lnx.azurewebsites.net/resizing-a-linux-vm-system-disk-in-microsoft-azure/)

[Expand virtual hard disks on a Linux VM with the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/expand-disks)